# Positiion of tongue during padmasana according to Hatha Yoga Pradipika

Tags: asana, hatha-yoga, padmasana

[Hatha Yoga Pradipika](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hyp/index.htm), in a verse on padmasana, mentions the position of tongue.

> Gaze on the tip of the nose, **keeping the tongue pressed against the
> root of the teeth of the upper jaw**, and the chin against the chest,
> and raise the air up slowly, i.e., pull the apâna-vâyû gently upwards.
>
> [[48, Chapter 1: On Âsanas]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hyp/hyp03.htm)

Should the tongue be in the same way as in pronouncing the letter L? Or any other position?

Is there any animated image or more explanation that can help us to understand it?